# Is it possible to have Orleans host without a client?

Tags: orleans

I have a grain that sets up a reminder in `OnActivate` method.
The reminder then periodically does some action and no further communication is needed from outside the silo.

Is it possible to get a GrainProvider during host start and activate the grain within the Host itself?

Or do I need a client to initiate the first activation?

Comment: Why would you use Orleans for that? Sounds like any plain old task scheduler will do.

Comment: Distributed task scheduler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call the grain in [Application Bootstrapping within a Silo](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Advanced-Concepts/Application-Bootstrap-within-a-Silo), which is called on silo startup. Calling the gets its `OnActicate` called. Some more documentation at
[Bootstrap provider](https://richorama.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/bootstrap-providers-in-orleans/).

It would be possible to insert the data straight to the persistent storage (via some side-channel) too, but that's a somewhat of an unsupport scenario (at the moment).

Comment: @Vojtech B Move your reminder creation into a grain method, and start from the bootstrapper code.